# DOSbox automatically freezes and crashes without any prompt warnings

Tags: assembly, x86-16, dos, dosbox

I was trying to run my assembly language program and it is when i try to enter the 2nd input, the cursor freezes and the DOSbox emulator would crash after a few seconds of delay.

I've tried running other assembly language programs and they seem to be working fine. Im not sure of the reason behind this, could it be an error in my code (MASM format) / not enough RAM to run the program? My code is attached below and I had 1.5GB of RAM available while I was running the program.

```
.MODEL SMALL
.STACK
.DATA
    msg1 DB "Quantity (unit): $"
    msg2 DB 13,10,"Unit price (RM): $"
    msg3 DB 13,10,"Total amount is RM$"
    Quantity DB 0
    Unit_price DB 0
    Total DB 0
    Q DB 0
    R DB 0
    
.CODE
MAIN PROC
    MOV AX, @DATA
    MOV DS, AX
    
    MOV AH, 09H
    LEA DX, msg1
    INT 21H
    
    MOV AH, 01H
    INT 21H
    MOV Quantity, AL
    
    MOV AH, 09H
    LEA DX, msg2
    INT 21H
    
    MOV AH, 01H
    INT 21H
    MOV Unit_price, AL
    
    MOV AH, 09H
    LEA AX, msg3
    INT 21H
    
    XOR AX, AX
    SUB Quantity, '0'
    SUB Unit_price, '0'
    
    MOV AL, Quantity
    MUL Unit_price
    MOV Total, AL
    
    XOR AX, AX
    MOV DX, 10H
    DIV DX
    MOV Q, AL
    MOV R, AH
    
    MOV AH, 02H
    MOV DL, Q
    INT 21H
    
    MOV AH, 02H
    MOV DL, R
    INT 21H
    
    MOV AH, 4CH
    INT 21H
    
MAIN ENDP
END MAIN
```

Comment: It could be (a long time since I used Masm) that you are trying to write invalid characters after calculating the total quantity. You need to add the base **"0"** to both `Q` and `R` before trying to display them at the console.

Comment: This generates divide error `LEA AX, msg3`.

Comment: `LEA AX, msg3` should be `LEA DX, msg3`. If you fix that the next problem is that your division will cause an overflow. DIV DX divides the 32 bit number in DX:AX by the 16-bit value in DX. So you effectively do 0x0010:0x0000 divided by 0x0010.. I recommend stepping through in a debugger.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Three bugs that I can see, including some spotted in comments.

---

```
    MOV AH, 09H
    LEA AX, msg3
    INT 21H
```

Looks like a typo for `LEA DX, msg3`.  As it stands you will have a random value in AH (the high byte of the address of `msg3` and will be executing some random DOS function.  That might be what crashes DosBox.

Also, more efficient than `LEA` here (and in the other similar instances) would be `MOV DX, OFFSET msg3` which has the same effect and saves one byte.

---

```
    XOR AX, AX
    MOV DX, 10H
    DIV DX
```

First, you zeroed out `AX` thus discarding the total value you so carefully computed (remember, `AX` emcompasses both `AH` and `AL`).  Second, `DIV r/m16` is a 32 by 16 bit division: it divides the 32-bit unsigned value in `DX:AX` by the value in `r/m16`, with the quotient placed in `AX` and the remainder in `DX`.  So here you are dividing `100000H` by `10H`; the quotient is `10000h` which overflows 16 bits, and so you will get a divide overflow exception.

This could also be the cause of the crash, though I seem to recall that real MS-DOS had a handler for the divide overflow interrupt that would print a message and terminate the program, without crashing the system.  I'm not sure if DosBox provides that, however.

Also, `10H` is hex, so you're dividing by sixteen.  I'm assuming you probably wanted decimal output, so you want to divide by ten (`10`) instead.

Thus, I think you probably meant

```
    XOR AH, AH    ; zero-extend AL into AX
    MOV DL, 10
    DIV DL
```

to do a 16 by 8 bit divide of the number from `AL` (extended with zeros to produce a 16-bit value in `AX`) by `10`, placing the quotient in `AL` and the remainder in `AH`.

---

```
    MOV AH, 02H
    MOV DL, Q
    INT 21H
```

You need to add `'0'` to the values `Q` and `R` to create printable ASCII characters for output.

Comment: A division exception will just crash on DOSBox unless you install your own handler.